# Loading multiple CSV files into one nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have multiple CSV files (one for each stock symbol) which I want to load into a nested dictionary like:

```
market_data["Symbol"] = { "Open": [], "High": [], "Low": [], "Close": [],
    "Volume": [], "Adjusted": [], "Date": [], "MA_10":[] }
```

I have a different CSV file for each symbol and each CSV file has the data such as Open, High, Low, etc. but not necessarily the same name. I want to load it into that data structure but I'm not able to figure it out.

I want it to look like :

> print market_data
>
> {'SYMBOL2': {'High': [20, 22, 23, 19, 21], 'Volume': [100, 200, 300,
>   400, 500], 'Adjusted': [12, 13, 14, 15, 16], 'Low': [10, 12, 13, 9,
>   1], 'MA_10': [], 'Date': ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03',
>   '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05'], 'Close': [15, 15, 15, 11, 16], 'Open':
>   [12, 13, 14, 15, 16]}, 'SYMBOL1': {'High': [20, 22, 23, 19, 21],
>   'Volume': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500], 'Adjusted': [12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
>   'Low': [10, 12, 13, 9, 1], 'MA_10': [], 'Date': ['2015-01-01',
>   '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05'], 'Close': [15,
>   15, 15, 11, 16], 'Open': [12, 13, 14, 15, 16]}}

Comment: Please provide some examples

Comment: Can you expand on where these csv files are coming from?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [mcve], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: I already have these csv files downloaded.

Comment: Where do you get the symbol from? is it contained in the file as well or is it a part of the filename?

Comment: It's a part of the filename. It's not there in the file. @jottbe

Comment: What does *"Each CSV file has the data such as Open, High, Low, etc. but not necessarily the same name"* mean? That the names might be slightly different like 'opening'/'closing'? or some keys might be missing? or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly, you can do it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
# enter your filenames in the list
# if they are in a particular directory
# you can also use os.listdir or something 
# like that to get the actual filenames
filenames= ['ibm.csv']
result_dict= dict()
for file in filenames:
    # load the csv in a dataframe
    df= pd.read_csv(file, sep=',')
    symbol= file.split('.')[0]
    symbol_dict= result_dict.setdefault(symbol, dict())
    # process the dataframe columnwise
    # turning each column into a key in the dict
    # and it's values into a list
    for col, ser in df.items():
        symbol_dict.setdefault(col, list()).extend(ser.to_list())
```

Comment: This only stores the information of the last file in the list for some reason

Comment: You're welcome. You probably looked at `symbol_dict`. The `result_dict` contains the infos of all files, I just verified that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does work, my bad! I was checking ```symbol_dict``` earlier .

Comment: No problem. Thank you for retesting.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I don't have a CSV like yours on me, but here is what I came up with. If you have a CSV I can play with, I will happily test it and make improvements.</s>

At the very least it seems to work with the AAPL.csv right now.

**Updated Version:**

```
import csv
market_data = {}
list_of_files = ['AAPL.csv']
for file in list_of_files:
        f = open(file, 'rt')
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        market_data[file] = {}
        flag = False
        headers = 0
        for row in reader:
                if (flag == False):
                        headers = row
                        for header in headers:
                                market_data[file][header] = []
                                flag = True
                else:
                        data = row
                        print(data)
                        for a, header in zip(data, headers):
                                market_data[file][header].append(a)

print(market_data)
```

Comment: I get an error in doing 'for row in reader', the error message says that list has no attribute split. Also, I do have a csv but I don't know how to send it to you.

Comment: 13mdg5@queensu.ca is my email. Or consider using https://justbeamit.com. And if row is a list, then perhaps that particular line is not required.

Comment: Happy to help. Any more questions, just comment here.

Comment: @smci: how exactly would you do that? I mean the question is not about writing/reading data, that is already in a dictionary-like structure, but reading data in table-like-structure and reading it into dictionaries. So it would rather be `df.to_dict` I think, but this wouldn't update an existing dictionary but create a new one for each symbol, so it would not work if there are several files with data for the same symbol.